# Add custom logging to Eclipse E4

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, slf4j, e4

I have an Eclipse E4 application and want to add some custom logging (with Logback) in it. But when I do this via the application lifecycle postContectCreate method it always give me a dialog with the exception in. I don't want that dialog but the logs should be written to a log file. How can I achieve this?

I tried:

```
 @PostContextCreate
  void postContextCreate(IEclipseContext workbenchContext) {

    ...

    workbenchContext.set(IEventLoopAdvisor.class, new EclipseLogs());
  }

public class EclipseLogs implements IEventLoopAdvisor {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EclipseLogs.class);

  @Override
  public void eventLoopException(Throwable e) {
    logger.error(e.getMessage(), GlobalData.getInstance().getCurrentUserName(), e);   
  }

  @Override
  public void eventLoopIdle(Display display) {
    display.sleep();
  }

}
```

My logback.xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>

    <appender name="TIME_BASED_FILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>logs/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} (%line\) -
                %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="ALL">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="TIME_BASED_FILE" />
    </root>

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.LEVEL" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

I want to have the exceptions thrown in my console terminal when running it from inside Eclipse itself, but when running as a standalone app it should write the exception to a log file.

The dialog itself looks like:
[image]

Comment: What is `Logger` and `LoggerFactory`?

Comment: import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

Comment: Is  the `eventLoopException` code being executed when you get an exception? If it is then this is a slf4j configuration issue. If the code is not being executed something else is handling the exception.

Comment: The eventLoopException is called when an exception occured. When I do e.printStackTrace(); in it, it give me also the exception dialog.

Comment: I can't think of anything that would show a dialog when calling e.printStacktrace. What does this dialog look like? Show us a picture.

Comment: Added screenshot of the dialog itself.

Comment: Well that looks like the dialog that is displayed by the default event loop advisor, I don't see a way that it could be called if your advisor was run.